# Using Python 3, why doesn't the int method handle strings that represent a float? Is this by design?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.5+, the following works without issue:

```
int("10")
```

However, when using the int method to convert a string that represents a float, it throws an error:

```
>>> int("10.0")

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10.0'
```

This can be solved by simply using:

```
>>> int(float("10.0"))
```

So to recap, int(x) can:

- Convert a string to an integer if x is of type string and represents an integer.
- Convert a float to an integer, if x is of type float.

**However, it cannot do both 1 and 2 simultaneously.**

Is there a reason why the language specification for Python doesn't allow for returning an integer from a string representing a float without having to cast to float first? Do other languages like Java require this intermediate step for strings representing a float?

Comment: Because `"10.0"` doesn't represent an `int`, the `int` constructor accepts strings that represent valid `int` literals, which seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: Yes, but int(10.0) works just fine. My question is why Python requires the intermediate step when, AFAIK, other languages with a parseInt function do not.

Comment: Yeah because `1.0` is **not a string**. And `int` isn't like java's `parseInt` at all. It is a *class constructor*. In Python, such a thing would be `int.parse_int`

Comment: python is so easy to use that sometimes it can confuse people.

Comment: And anyway (had to actually checkt his for myself) `Integer.parseInt` raises an exception with `"10.0"` in Java as well...

Comment: "Convert a float to an integer, if the value is of type float." What does this even mean? A `float` is *always* of type `float`

Comment: "Convert a float to an integer, if the value is of type float."  (if x is of type float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is a class, which takes argument(s) in its constructor.

If the first argument is a *string*, and no other argument is provided, python tries to parse the string argument as a decimal integer. Any other character triggers an exception.

Note that `int("3E",16)` works, but only because the string is compatible with 16 base. And `int('002')` works too where `int(002)` doesn't as `002` isn't a valid integer in python anymore (leading zeros aren't allowed).

When passing an integer, `int` just returns the same object exactly (no need to build another one since integers are immutable), and when passing a float, `int` constructor truncates the value to integer.

So `int` constructor is already very easy to use, but it's also safe against misuses.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and insight.